# UPDATE database and SELECT at once

Tags: php

I'm trying to update a database and after updating I would like to send an email to the customer.

Following code works fine, but is not showing the variable in the body of the e-mail.

```
if (!isset ($_GET['token']))
{
echo "Link is missing";
}
else
{
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE account SET verified = ? WHERE token = ?");
$status = 1;
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $status, $token);
$res = $stmt->execute();
if ($res)
{
echo "name updated";
}
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM account WHERE token = ?");
$stmt1->bind_param("s", $token);
$res1 = $stmt1->execute();
if ($res1)
{
$name = $row["name"]; // THIS DOES NOT WORK
$fromemail = "post@postmaster.com";
$fromname = "Postmaster Inc.";
$subject = "Updating your account";
$to = "member@postmaster.com";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$fromname." <".$fromemail.">\r\n";
$message = "$name"; // NOT VISIBLE IN E-MAIL
mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
}
```

Is there a way to define the variable for the e-mail? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it correct that `$row` is undefined? Check the error log, or switch on error reporting to see the error messages that help you detect problems like this.

Comment: You execute the select statement, but never retrieve the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i updated your code, give it a try

```
if (!isset($_GET['token'])) {
    echo "Link is missing";
} else {
    // Assuming $conn is your database connection
    
    // Update the 'verified' field
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE account SET verified = ? WHERE token = ?");
    $status = 1;
    $token = $_GET['token']; // Retrieve token from $_GET
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $status, $token);
    $res = $stmt->execute();
    
    if ($res) {
        echo "Account verified successfully";
        
        // Fetch the updated row to get the name
        $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM account WHERE token = ?");
        $stmt1->bind_param("s", $token);
        $res1 = $stmt1->execute();
        
        if ($res1) {
            $result = $stmt1->get_result();
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $name = $row["name"];
            
            // Compose and send the email
            $fromemail = "post@postmaster.com";
            $fromname = "Postmaster Inc.";
            $subject = "Updating your account";
            $to = "member@postmaster.com";
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "From: " . $fromname . " <" . $fromemail . ">\r\n";
            $message = "Hello $name, your account has been updated."; // Use $name in the email body
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            
            echo "Email sent successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Failed to fetch the updated information from the database";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Failed to update the account";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, Mehdi, it works fine! Many many thanks from me and my customers.
It is really amazing to see how fast you did fix this :-)

Comment: @MichaëlThönnissen you're welcome :-D